# How do I add arbitrary fields to a model in Django/MongoDB

Tags: django, mongodb, django-models

I thought part of the power of MongoDB was being able to add arbitrary fields to a DB model at any time.  In Django with MongoDB, I can add a field to a model at any time without having to merge everything, but how do I add a field to only one "row" in the DB table.  In other words, I don't want to add the field to the model definition, because it may only show up on one or two rows, so instead it should be added when the row is saved to the database.